# Guillaume Kurkdjian Water Material

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, workflow

Guillaume Kurkdjian has this really cool water:
[image]
How can I achieve this water in blender cycles? (material and modeling of the water)

The closest I've gotten is this:

[image]

This is the material settings for the image above:

[image]

Comment: @cegaton Updated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you added detail to  your questions, share not only the results but the settings you are using to get there, like Images of your nodes and the mesh.

Comment: @cegaton Sorry for that, edited again!

Comment: Looks to me like there's probably some Volume Scatter in there too. Look at how the land interacts with the water on the left side, in the shadow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a try:

[image]

### Analysis:

According to the source artwork, there may be some shaders used. However, the key parts can be: Glass/Refraction, Translucent, Glossy, etc.

So after a few trial and errors, a possible setup might be:

[image]

Besides, post processing like compositing can also be included:

[image]

To model the water shape, here is one way:
[image]

Example file: [image]

Answer (score 5):

Just put the IOR at 0.9, roughness at 0.2 and make the background white at 1 energy + a sun lamp with 1 energy

[image]

[image]