# Water material that is semi transparent

Tags: materials

is it possible to have a water material that reveals the beach sand below it like in the photo below?
and the color of the water interacts with the color of the underlying material aka, sand.

thank you. 
[image: ,]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56963/guillaume-kurkdjian-water-material/57258#57258

Comment: Have you tried a [volume shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/volume.html)?

Comment: Or maybe here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107236/how-to-make-my-water-look-murky

Comment: thank you @cgslav this is the best possible approach until now